# covert textbox value to [3x][3x][3x]

Tags: vb.net

I need a way to convert textbox value into following format:

[image]

it should return back Eight [xx],[30] at beginning if digit does not exist on that place and [3x] for the place where digit exist

I have written the following code:

```
Imports System.Text

Dim number As Integer = "1234527"
    Dim finalres As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim res As Integer() = {30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30}
    With Nothing
        Dim i As Integer = 7
        While i >= 0
            If (number > 0) Then
                Dim [rem] As Integer = number Mod 10
                number = (number / 10)
                Dim n As Integer = 30 + [rem]
                Dim s As String = "[" + n.ToString() + "]"
                finalres.Insert(0, s)
            Else
                finalres.Insert(0, "[" + 30.ToString() + "]")
            End If
            Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(i), i + 1)
End While
End With
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", finalres))

MsgBox(finalres.ToString)
```

but this is returning some output right and some wrong, for example in this case when number = 1234527, it is returning [30][31][32][33][34][35][33][37]
whereas my desired output is [30][31][32][33][34][35][32][37]

Comment: What have you doner and where are you stuck? It's not for us to just write your code for you. You need to make an effort. Consider the logic first, formalise that logic into an algorithm and then write code to implement that algorithm. If it doesn't work as expected, you can show us the code you've written and explain exactly where in the algorithm it does produce the expected results. If you haven't even considered the logic, as appears to be the case, then you don't even have a programming problem yet.

Comment: Hint: you can use [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-6.0#system-string-padleft(system-int32-system-char)) to prepend the missing zeroes.

Comment: I notice that the code tries to assign a string (`"1234527"`) to an Integer. To avoid errors like that, I recommend that you set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project, and make it the default for new projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly to deal with the error in your code.  You are sometimes seeing incorrect results because of rounding when you do integer division.  The solution is to remove the remainder before dividing by 10.  Change the relevant line to:

```
number = ((number - [rem]) / 10)
```

However the task can be achieved far more simply, if you convert the entire integer to a string, using `PadLeft` to add any required 0s.  Then all you have to do is loop through the resultant 8 character string like this:

```
Dim number As Integer = 1234527
Dim strNumber As String = number.ToString.PadLeft(8, "0")

Dim finalres As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
For i As Integer = 0 To 7
    finalres.Append("[3" + strNumber(i) + "]")
Next

MessageBox.Show(finalres.ToString)
```

By way of explanation, `PadLeft` can take a second parameter specifying the character to be used for the padding, in this case 0.

Any `string` can be treated as an `Array`, so that you can refer to the individual characters within the string by their (0 based) index position.

Comment: Or `Dim b = String.Concat(number.PadLeft(8, "0"c).Select(Function(d) $"[3{d}]"))` if you like using LINQ; the question says the value came from a TextBox, so the ToString() is likely to be redundant.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes the initial ToString probably is redundant,  but I left it to conform as closely as possible to OP's version (without the quotes). I like your LINQ! Might have a job explaining it to a newbie though. 